# I want my query to show total sales from separate storefronts

Tags: ms-access

My Access database contains sales information for a bookstore that has both a physical store and an online shop. Sales and Book info are stored in two separate tables, both linked by ISBN columns. Basically the Sales table just stores history of each individual transaction, including whether the purchase was made Online or In-store. I can easily count the total sales for each book via the Design interface. However, I also would like to have two columns with the totals for In-Store sales and Online sales. The Design interface won't allow me to provide different criteria manipulating the same column:

```
          Store      Store
          Sales      Sales
Criteria  ="Online"  ="Instore"
```

How would I go about providing this information in a single query?

Comment: You need to Group By the store. But first browse for a tutorial in SQL or something like "Get Started with Microsoft Access".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a crosstab query.

Otherwise, you have to create two calculated fields in your query. 
For example, if “Storefronts” is the field that shows the value “Instore” and “Online”, while the field “Sales” shows the sales value, you can do in this way:

```
Online_sales: iif([Storefronts] = “Online”; [Sales]; 0)
Instore_sales: iif([Storefronts] = “Instore”; “Sales”; 0)
```

After saving, click Totals and in the Total row leave Group By for the Book_name field and change the value to Sum for the calculated fields. Then save the query.